# Recursive order of a Haskell program that splits a string into a string of strings

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm carrying on with learning Haskell, and I've defined a program called SplitUp to be as follows:

```
splitUp :: [Char] -> String -> (String, [String])
splitUp separators [] = ("",[""])
splitUp separators (x:xs)
   | elem x separators          = (x : separatorslist, ("":word:words))
   | otherwise           = (separatorslist, ((x:word):words))
     where
       (separatorslist,word:words) = split separators xs
```

What splitUp does is that it splits up a string and its separators. For example, "One. Word!" would go to ". !", " "One", "Word""

What I don't understand is why with the way that the program is set up why the input isn't given in reverse order with the recursion of x:word:words? Because if we are adding x to the front of the list of (word:words) and recursing shouldn't it give back something like droW enO?

Comment: Why do you think that the output should be reversed? The list is deconstructed from the front, and elements are only put back at the front.

Comment: Thanks, though I guess I should try to be a bit more clear as to what I am trying to say here :).                                                                                                              For example, I have the program that returns split separators and words. Let's say, for example, that I want to do "!", "A string!" in the program. So, this is a list of the form (x:xs), right? Where x is an element being added to the front of the list using ':' . So it will go through the list of "A string!", and will create the string of strings (separatorslist, ((x:word:words))

Comment: But it is that part (x:word) that gets me out, we are adding x from the "A string!" to the front of the new list word:words, so shouldn't this add A first, then space, then s in front of the A? Like "gnirts A"?

Comment: `x` is the first letter of the word. `word` is the rest of the word, split off from the rest of the string `xs`. To get the word in the correct order, you put the first character first... so obviously it would `x:word`.

Comment: But we are doing x:word:words. Word:words is initially an empty list, and x:xs adds an element onto the front of xs. So, if we are taking apart a word, let's say, "sentence", it will first add s to the empty list, then e, etc, so wouldn't it become ecnetnes?

Comment: It does *not* at the character `s` to the empty list. It adds the character `s` to the list which is the result of calling the function recursively on `xs`.

Comment: I guess my main confusion comes from this part - (separatorslist,word:words) = split separators xs. What exactly is it doing here?

Comment: `(separatorslist,word:words) = split separators xs` calls the function `split seperators xs`, which returns a tuple. The left hand side binds the variables `seperatorslist` for the first element of the tuple, and `word:words` for the second element. `word` is the first word; `words` are the rest of the words.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but I'm still finding it very difficult to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Let's say we take "!" "A few words!"

This is splitUp "!" "A: few words!"

So it will go to the otherwise clause for A, hence = ([], a:[])

Then it will do splitUp "!" " few words!", so 

= ([], f:[a])


Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The value `([], a:[])` is never constructed. `a` is appended to the result of the recursive computation. In this case, this is `splitUp "!" " few words!"` - this should return `[" few words", ""]`; then `'A'` is appended to this first word, forming the result: `["A few words", ""]`.

Comment: So what's the first element put into word:words?

Comment: I guess I understand everything, just not how exactly word:words is defined here. I've heard something about tail recursion? Thank for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to give a general answer to what I believe the misunderstanding is.

Let's define a simple recursive function that will just take a string and put it back together.

```
rewrite :: String -> String
rewrite []     = ""
rewrite x      = x
rewrite (x:xs) = x : rewrite xs
```

As you can see, I'm putting `x` at the beginning of the list and appending the recursive call, similarly to your example. This will just give me the starting string itself, not its reverse. Let's take a look at a step-by-step example passing "Hello" to the function.

```
rewrite "Hello" = 'H' : rewrite "ello"
                = 'H' : 'e' : rewrite "llo"
                = 'H' : 'e' : 'l' : rewrite "lo"
                = 'H' : 'e' : 'l' : 'l' : rewrite "o"
                = 'H' : 'e' : 'l' : 'l' : 'o'
                = "Hello" -- and we're done
```

Comment: I try to explain my q in an above comment ^